# Execute an objects method without making a new instance

Tags: object, methods, instance

How can I execute `Print` from within `TestObject`?

```
class Program
{
    private int Value;
    static void Main()
    {
        TestObject test = new TestObject();
        Program p1 = new Program();
        Program p2 = new Program();
        p1.Value = 1;
        p2.Value = 2;
        p1.Print();
        p2.Print();
    } 

    private void Print()
    {
        Console.Write(Value.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class TestObject
{
    // How to execute p1.Print here?
}
```

Comment: Make `Print` static or create an instance, that's your choices.

Comment: edited the question so it is relevant of which object the method is called. is there no way to do that?

Comment: You cannot call instance methods without an instance. It doesn't matter which object or type or method it is, you simply cannot do it.

Comment: You *can*, however, pass an instance of `Program` to `TestObject`, that way it will have an instance to call the method on. Add a constructor to `TestObject` that accepts an instance of `Program` and then make `Print` public. **Or** you can pass in a delegate, add a constructor to `TestObject` that accepts an instance of the `Action` delegate and construct it with `new TestObject(() => Print());` then call the delegate from within `TestObject `.

Comment: can you provide an example? feel free to change `TestObject` to your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this:

### Pass Program directly to TestObject

Pros:

- Simple change

Cons:

- You will have to make `Print` public
- You will expose other things in Program
- You're coupling `TestObject` to `Program` directly

Here's sample code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TestObject test = new TestObject(this);
    } 

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.Write(Value.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class TestObject
{
    public TestObject(Program p)
    {
        p.Print();
    }
}
```

### Pass a delegate to TestObject

Pros:

- Simple change
- Doesn't have to make `Print` public
- Only exposes 1 method to `TestObject`

Cons:

- The coupling is `TestObject` wants to do something, not `TestObject` wants access to something that does something

Here's sample code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TestObject test = new TestObject(() => Print());
    } 

    private void Print()
    {
        Console.Write(Value.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class TestObject
{
    public TestObject(Action print)
    {
        print();
    }
}
```

### Implement an interface in Program and pass it to TestObject

Pros:

- Only exposes what the interface exposes
- Easier to implement other places (better to say "need this interface" than "needs a delegate", clearer contract specification)
- No coupling to a specific type, coupling is to *any object that meets certain criteria - implements an interface*

Cons:

- None relevant *(in my opinion)*

Here's sample code:

```
interface IPrintable
{
    void Print();
}

class Program : IPrintable
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TestObject test = new TestObject(this);
    } 

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.Write(Value.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class TestObject
{
    public TestObject(IPrintable p)
    {
        p.Print();
    }
}
```

---

**Conclusion**: My advice would be to pick the interface way. Clearer design, easier to extend without having multiple delegates being passed around.